# mongoose retrieve only inserted in push

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I retrieve only the inserted object in the clients array, I insert and then in callback I have all clients and I wanna only the inserted.

```
 User.findOneAndUpdate(
        {_id: req.body.id },
        { $push: { clients: { 

            name: req.body.name,
            tel: req.body.tel,
            itens: req.body.itens

        } } }, {safe: true},

        function(err, model) {

            if(err){

            console.log(err);

            }
            if(!model){

            console.log('Not Found')

            }
            var itens= model.itens;
            //print all clients i wanna to print only the inserted
            console.log(itens);
        }

    );
```

Comment: I'm just trying to understand your use case. Why do you need the inserted items in the callback ? Isn't that all input items(`req.body.itens`) that you just inserted ? Its an atomic update so its all-or-none.

Comment: yes, but when i print model he give me all client i just want the last inserted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I handle it rather than using findOneAndUpdate. I use findOne and then add my object and then push to the array and then save.

```
User.findOne({_id: req.body.id }, function(err, model) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        if(!model){
            console.log('Not Found');
        }

        var itemToPush = { 
            _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            name: req.body.name,
            tel: req.body.tel,
            itens: req.body.itens
        }; 

        model.clients.push(itemtToPush);
        model.save(function(err,model){
            console.log(itemToPush._id);
            console.log(itemToPush);
        });

    }

);
```

I am not sure if you are looking for any id or not but that should give you the object you wish to push. Again, might not be the solution you are looking for.

Comment: i need the _id too

Comment: You could also just add the _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId() to the itemToPush. this way you already get the id for it.. Updated the answer.

Comment: your solution work, but if i use { new: true } and then console.log( model.clients[model.clients.length-1])work too without need to generate a key before the mongo insert